# How to find out what pandas/pickle version I need to unpickle a file?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have the latest pandas version and am trying to unpickle a file from [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/courses/CSC2541_Winter17/project_2.pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eurtasun/courses/CSC2541_Winter17/project_2.pdf), more specifically from this link [http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~namdar/sports_course/sportvue/raptors.7z](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Enamdar/sports_course/sportvue/raptors.7z)

```
data = pickle.load(open(f, 'rb'))
```

but receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_data.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = pickle.load(open(f, 'rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'
```

I am using python3.7 and the latest pandas. I read from [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285798/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-core-indexes) that I should use the latest version but I have the version at 1.1.3. The only other way mentioned here [Python -- read_pickle ImportError: No module named indexes.base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888228/python-read-pickle-importerror-no-module-named-indexes-base) is to use a specific pandas version.

How do I check what version I need to open that file?

Comment: It looks like this is part of an assignment. Did you try asking the professor about the version requirements?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am not in that school, I just wanted to use the dataset for my own project. Is there no way to load it?